# JSP defining values

Tags: java, jsp, url, concatenation

I have two values in JSP. For 1 I defined `a=http://` and for 2nd I defined `b=google.com` Currently I am using `concat_urls= "<%=a%><%=b%>"` . Can I join them as `concat_urls= "<%=ab%>"`

Comment: **NO** `ab` will be interpreted as new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. However, expression in `<%= ... %>` is a normal Java expression, so you can write

```
<%= a + b %>
```

Also note that in general use of scriptlets [is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 0):

### NO

`ab` will be interpreted as new variable. You can do this `<%= a+b %>`